# Brand filtering on category pages

Tags: bigcommerce

In Bigcommerce, is it possible to add brand filtering to category pages?

The current options appear to be that you can select from "all brands" by visiting the brands page, or you could use the search engine to narrow your results but you're forced to type a keyword or space. I want to offer a way to narrow the products by brand for the specific category the user is viewing.

I've spoken to tech support and they've informed me that this is NOT an option through the control panel and would have to be done through the API.

In my attempt to do this with the API however, it doesn't appear there is anyway to dynamically identify which category a user viewing. Outside of hard-coding a template for each individual category, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was informed by API support that this is NOT possible. Their recommendation was to submit the idea to the support team for future implementation, and that I might be able to accomplish it through a combination of javascript and screen scraping.